# Peskin and Schröeder page 195, IR divergence in the electron vertex function, rewriting integral

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, notation, feynman-diagrams, integration

Peskin and Schröeder make the following statement
$$\int_0^1dxdydz\ \delta(x+y+z-1)\frac{1-4z+z^2}{\Delta(q^2=0)}=\int_0^1dz\int_0^{1-z}dy\frac{-2+(1-z)(3-z)}{m^2(1-z)^2},\tag{p.195}$$

where $$\Delta = - xyq^2+(1-z)^2m^2.\tag{p.192}$$

Why does the integral of $dy$ go from $0$ to $1-z$ and not from $0$ to $1$? Also the meaning of the integral bound on the LHS is unclear for me, since we see only one integral bound, but we have three integration variables.

Comment: Hint: Draw the integration region on both sides keeping the delta function in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$  \begin{align} {\rm LHS} &\equiv\int\limits_0^1 \! dz \int\limits_0^1\! dy \int\limits_0^1\! dx \; \delta(x+y+z-1) f(x,y,z)\\ &= \int\limits_0^1 \! dz \int\limits_0^1 \! dy \int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\! \!\!dx \;\Theta(x) \Theta(1-x) \delta(x+y+z-1) f(x,y,z)  \\   &=\int\limits_0^1 \! dz \int\limits_0^1 \! dy \;\Theta(1-y-z) \Theta(y+z) f(1-y-z,y,z)\\ &=\int\limits_0^1 \! dz \int\limits_0^{1-z} \! \! \! dy \; f(1-y-z,y,z).  \end{align} $$